# desktopCapturer - how to prove audio is coming through?

Tags: node.js, electron, desktopcapturer

I have the following code that attempts to capture audio/video from a specific application running on my windows desktop:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>Audio and Video</title>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <video autoplay></video>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         var desktopCapturer = require('electron').desktopCapturer;
         console.log("are you here?")
         console.log(desktopCapturer)

         desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] }).then(async sources => {
            for (const source of sources) {
               if (source.name === 'MyStreamingApp') {
                  try {
                  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                     audio: {
                        mandatory: {
                        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                        chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
                        }
                     },
                     video: {
                        mandatory: {
                        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                        chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
                        minWidth: 1280,
                        maxWidth: 1280,
                        minHeight: 720,
                        maxHeight: 720
                        }
                     }
                  })
                  handleStream(stream)
                  } catch (e) {
                  handleError(e)
                  }
                  return
               }
            }
            })

            function handleStream (stream) {
            const video = document.querySelector('video')
            video.srcObject = stream
            video.onloadedmetadata = (e) => video.play()
            }

            function handleError (e) {
            console.log(e)
            }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I run this, I can hear audio... but of course I can't tell if the audio is coming from the original windows app or the electron app

**Questions**

Any suggestions on how to test this?   How can i prove to myself that the the electron app is sending audio too?  For example, is there a way to "tell" electron to play the audio using a specific device instead of just on default speakers / output for computer?

I'm assuming this is the way to capture audio/video from a specific application that's running instead of getting a/v from the system's speakers in general.
Is this assumption correct?

**Edit 1**

Since posting, I combed over this manual:

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer?q=console.log

I changed the code so that for the audio, I don't specify a source id, like so:

```
              const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                 audio: {
                    mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                    //when capturing audio, need to remove the sourceid constraint.
                    //chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
                    }
                 },
                 video: {
                    mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                    chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
                    minWidth: 1280,
                    maxWidth: 1280,
                    minHeight: 720,
                    maxHeight: 720
                    }
                 }
              })
```

And now... when I start the electron app and start my av app, the electron app send chopped audio.  it's so badly mangled I can't make out anything ...
Meanwhile, i can still hear the audio from the source application.  So I guess I've proven it's capturing some audio ... but it's so bad, it's unusable.

Based on the notes in the documentation, the fact that it says NOT to specify a sourceID when streaming audio, I'm going to guess that you can use electron as is to get audio from a specific windows application .  You can only request the entire desktop audio.  But it'd be nice if someone with more experience can confirm.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the same issue - need to get a specified window audio, but only the entrire desktop audio comes.